# IntelliSense in .fsx and dynamically loaded assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense, f#-scripting

When dynamically referencing assemblies in .fsx using `#I` and `#r`, VS highlights the following usages of imported types and writes "The namespace or module 'XXX' is not defined". Is it ok?

For example, in the following code

```
#I @".\Tools\FAKE"
#r "FakeLib.dll"

open Fake

Target "Hello" (fun _ -> trace "hello!")

Run "Hello"
```

VS highlights `Fake` and says "The namespace or module 'Fake' is not defined", it also highlights `Target` and `Run`. I have this problem in VS 2010 SP1 and in VS 11 CTP. This issue makes writing F# scripts a bit harder task than it could be.

By the way, IntelliSence for "common" types works well. `FakeLib.dll` and `FakeLib.xml` are present in the `.\Tools\FAKE` directory. The code runs well.

**Update 1**
Here's the screenshot of the situation. You can see that VS resolves assembly `FakeLib` correctly (in a tooltip), and that at the same time Intellisense "see" standard types (tooltip over `Console`) class.

[image]

**Update 2**
I think there's something wrong with the IntelliSense on my work workstation, because it (IntelliSense) behaves itself quite strange. When I start VS and open .fsx file, IntelliSense refuses to resolve even standard types/classes, and it doesn't underlines `FAKE` classes, it does nothing. But after some period of time and some manipulation over code IntelliSense starts working for standard types and underlines `FAKE` types.

Moreover, when I've created the similar code on my home workstation there were no problems, IntelliSense works as it should.

Comment: The answer by Ryan Riley is absolutely correct. I don't know what's going on, but `#I` definitely breaks IntelliSense on both my workstations. The problems go away as soon as I remove `#I`.

Comment: Same thing here; in VS 2010 Premium F# scipt files, Intellisense does not work when referencing non-System dlls using #I and relative paths with #r.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the full path into the #r directive, you'll get full IntelliSense. The #I directive, while convenient, prevents IntelliSense from working properly though the code will run just fine. This is true for both loose scripts and those found in projects. Have a look at Tomas Petricek's [FSharp.AsyncExtensions](http://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.AsyncExtensions] project.

Comment: That's not true. `#I` seems to resolve correctly, with working Intellisense, in my case.

Comment: That's interesting. It's never worked for me in either VS 2010 Pro or Ultimate. Which VS are you using?

Comment: I also use ``#I`` quite frequently, it never failed me. 2010 Professional (not SP1).

Comment: That's very strange. Something must be happening somewhere, but neither my laptop nor my workstation provide IntelliSense when using #I. I always see the squiggles. However, I generally use vim when editing .fsx files, so I don't really notice the loss.

Comment: I had the same issue (in 2012 Ultimate) and just fixed it by removing #I directive! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you; the intermittent failures of intellisense in FAKE scripts has been driving me nuts. Full paths in the #r statements rather than using #I has fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue in VS 2015 update 1.

Comment: VS2015 update 3 - and if I use `#I` I get all kinds of intellisense and error highlighting issues. take them out, and it's warp speed ahead.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not how it works. Does your code run? Intellisense is provided for assemblies referenced using `#r`.

Comment: Yes, my code runs perfectly. I've updated my question with full .fsx file, when I load it to F# interractive, it executes well.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Have you tried with FAKE lib? I've restarted VS. The warnings had disapeared for a while but during that period IntelliSense didn't worked at all. After some period (1-2 minutes) IntelliSense turned on back, but the warning on FAKE constructs appeared either. BTW, I've created a solution and added .fsx as `Solution Items` item... nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe that makes a difference (although it shouldn't). My .fsx files are part of a project.

Comment: I've tried to include .fsx into the project, and it hasn't helped. I suspect there's some problems with IntelliSense in my workstation. See the update to question.