# VS 2015 F# Script Intellisense not loading

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense

My F# script intellisense stopped working out of the blue.  This happened in VS2012 also, so I installed 2015 on the same PC (~1 year ago), which worked until now.

[image]

The #r all point to valid dlls, and the code executes perfectly fine, but intellisense just hangs forever.

Comment: Since it works before, right? Please try to create a new F# project and check this issue again. If this issue persists, you can have a try with run the command: devenv /resetuserdata, /safemode, /resetsettings to troubleshot the VS factors, or go to Control Panel-Programs and Features and right click the VS 2015 to repair. If the new project works fine, which means this issue only happens for this special project, please close VS, unload then reload the solution, or clean the solution, delete the .suo or .vs of your current project, then reopen this solution to test this issue.

Comment: Are you using any type providers? Also, do you have `FSharp.Core.dll` anywhere in directories referenced by `#r` (there used to be a bug about that)? If you can share what DLLs are you loading and what other files are in the directories containing those DLLs, then people might be able to help a bit better...

Comment: @Sara-MSFT F# Intellisense in the Visual Studio 2015 Immediate Window is known to have problems. It is known for example to pick the wrong FSharp.Core version. Applying such default actions as resetting or (shudder) repairing can be very expensive without any benefites. This should be suggested only as a measure of last resort

Answer (score 0):

Try using full paths. Intellisense has issues sometimes without them in .fsx files

see 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7501282/57883